# How to extract multiple grandchildren/children from XML where one child is a specific value?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with an XML file that stores all "versions" of the chatbot we create. Currently we have 18 versions and I only care about the most recent one.  I'm trying to find a way to extract all `botDialogGroup` elements along with their associated `label` element for this "v18".  There's a one-to-many relationship between 'botDialogGroup' and 'label'.

Here's a snippet of XML where I have the `botDialogGroup` called "Transfer" and the `label` called  "Transfer with a question".  Not that this is only one version of the Bot, there are a total of 18.

Link to a sample XML file.  https://pastebin.com/aaDfBPUm

Also to note, `fullName` is the child of `botVersions`.  Whereas `botDialogGroup` and `label` for the grandchild of `botVersions`, and their parent is `botDialogs`.

```
<Bot>
  <botVersions>
    <fullName>v18</fullName>
    <botDialogs>
        <botDialogGroup>Transfer</botDialogGroup>
        <botSteps>
            <botVariableOperation>
                <askCollectIfSet>false</askCollectIfSet>
                <botMessages>
                    <message>Would you like to chat with an agent?</message>
                </botMessages>
                <botQuickReplyOptions>
                    <literalValue>Yes</literalValue>
                </botQuickReplyOptions>
                <botQuickReplyOptions>
                    <literalValue>No</literalValue>
                </botQuickReplyOptions>
                <botVariableOperands>
                    <disableAutoFill>true</disableAutoFill>
                    <sourceName>YesOrNoChoices</sourceName>
                    <sourceType>MlSlotClass</sourceType>
                    <targetName>Transfer_To_Agent</targetName>
                    <targetType>ConversationVariable</targetType>
                </botVariableOperands>
                <optionalCollect>false</optionalCollect>
                <quickReplyType>Static</quickReplyType>
                <quickReplyWidgetType>Buttons</quickReplyWidgetType>
                <retryMessages>
                    <message>I&apos;m sorry, I didn&apos;t understand that. You have to select an option to proceed.</message>
                </retryMessages>
                <type>Collect</type>
            </botVariableOperation>
            <type>VariableOperation</type>
        </botSteps>
        <botSteps>
            <botStepConditions>
                <leftOperandName>Transfer_To_Agent</leftOperandName>
                <leftOperandType>ConversationVariable</leftOperandType>
                <operatorType>Equals</operatorType>
                <rightOperandValue>No</rightOperandValue>
            </botStepConditions>
            <botSteps>
                <botVariableOperation>
                    <botVariableOperands>
                        <targetName>Transfer_To_Agent</targetName>
                        <targetType>ConversationVariable</targetType>
                    </botVariableOperands>
                    <type>Unset</type>
                </botVariableOperation>
                <type>VariableOperation</type>
            </botSteps>
            <botSteps>
                <botNavigation>
                    <botNavigationLinks>
                        <targetBotDialog>Main_Menu</targetBotDialog>
                    </botNavigationLinks>
                    <type>Redirect</type>
                </botNavigation>
                <type>Navigation</type>
            </botSteps>
            <type>Group</type>
        </botSteps>
        <botSteps>
            <botStepConditions>
                <leftOperandName>Transfer_To_Agent</leftOperandName>
                <leftOperandType>ConversationVariable</leftOperandType>
                <operatorType>Equals</operatorType>
                <rightOperandValue>Yes</rightOperandValue>
            </botStepConditions>
            <botStepConditions>
                <leftOperandName>Online_Product</leftOperandName>
                <leftOperandType>ConversationVariable</leftOperandType>
                <operatorType>NotEquals</operatorType>
                <rightOperandValue>OTP</rightOperandValue>
            </botStepConditions>
            <botStepConditions>
                <leftOperandName>Online_Product</leftOperandName>
                <leftOperandType>ConversationVariable</leftOperandType>
                <operatorType>NotEquals</operatorType>
                <rightOperandValue>TCF</rightOperandValue>
            </botStepConditions>
            <botSteps>
                <botVariableOperation>
                    <botVariableOperands>
                        <targetName>Transfer_To_Agent</targetName>
                        <targetType>ConversationVariable</targetType>
                    </botVariableOperands>
                    <type>Unset</type>
                </botVariableOperation>
                <type>VariableOperation</type>
            </botSteps>
            <botSteps>
                <botNavigation>
                    <botNavigationLinks>
                        <targetBotDialog>Find_Business_Hours</targetBotDialog>
                    </botNavigationLinks>
                    <type>Call</type>
                </botNavigation>
                <type>Navigation</type>
            </botSteps>
            <type>Group</type>
        </botSteps>
        <botSteps>
            <botNavigation>
                <botNavigationLinks>
                    <targetBotDialog>Direct_Transfer</targetBotDialog>
                </botNavigationLinks>
                <type>Redirect</type>
            </botNavigation>
            <type>Navigation</type>
        </botSteps>
        <developerName>Transfer_To_Agent</developerName>
        <label>Transfer with a question</label>
        <mlIntent>Transfer_To_Agent</mlIntent>
        <mlIntentTrainingEnabled>true</mlIntentTrainingEnabled>
        <showInFooterMenu>false</showInFooterMenu>
    </botDialogs>
</botVersions>
</Bot>
```

**Current script**

The problem I have is that it will search the entire tree, all 18 versions, for the `botDialogGroup` and `label` elements because i'm using `findall()`.  Whereas I only want it to search the `botVersions` of the most recent `fullName`, in this case is "v18".

Manually entering "v18" isn't a problem since I always know the version to look for.  And it's useful since different bots have different versions.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

cols = ["BotVersion", "DialogGroup", "Dialog"]
rows = []

tree = ET.parse('ChattyBot.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for fullName in root.findall(".//fullName[.='v18']"):
    for botDialogGroup in root.findall(".//botDialogGroup"):
        for label in root.findall(".//label"):
            print(fullName.text, botDialogGroup.text, label.text)
            rows.append({"BotVersion": fullName.text,
            "DialogGroup": botDialogGroup.text,
            "Dialog": label.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

df.to_csv("botcsvfile.csv")
```

Desired end result saved to a csv file using pandas.

| BotVersion | DialogGroup | Dialog |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v18 | Transfer | Transfer with a question |

Comment: what if the last version is v19? Do you need to modify the code?

Comment: @balderman Yes I would download a new XML file, change the version to "v19", and run the script.  This is expected as there are multiple bots all with varying number of versions.

Comment: how many entries like `<fullName>vXY</fullName>` the xml can contain? What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: There is one entry per version.  I don't believe there is a limit to the number of versions that can be created.

Comment: Problem with current code is as stated, where I have 18 versions it will search all 18 for the `botDialogGroup` and `label` elements.  I only want it to search the most recent, in this case version 18, for those elements.

Comment: you have 3 nested for loops. each time you call `findall` but you start the search from `root`. this is a bug. you want to do the search form the iterator of the loop. (`botDialogGroup .findall()`)

Comment: @balderman 
I'm not experienced with XML so I'm a bit lost. How would that work since the `botDialogGroup` element doesn't have any children? The `label` element is a child of `botDialogs`.

Comment: It's far simpler to accomplish if you use lxml instead of elementtree.

Comment: @JackFleeting I've never used lxml and this is my first time with an xml document.  How will lxml make simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this code makes the assumption that your XML is going to be of the pattern of `version, dialog1, dialog2, dialog3, version2, dialog1, dialog2, etc...` if this is not the case then let me know and I will reevaluate the code. But basically loop over the code and creating groups of dialogs too versions then sort by version number.  After that flatten to get a nested list form to create the pandas dataframe.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

cols = ["BotVersion", "DialogGroup", "Dialog"]
rows = []

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for fullName in root.findall(".//botVersions"):
    versions = list(fullName)

# creating the many to one relation between the versions and bot dialogs
grouping = []
relations = []
for i, tag in enumerate(versions):
    if i == 0:
        relations.append(tag)
    elif tag.tag == 'fullName':
        grouping.append(relations)
        relations = []
        relations.append(tag)
    else:
        relations.append(tag)
        # edge case for end of list)
        if i == len(versions) - 1:
            grouping.append(relations)

#sorting by the text of the fullName tag to be able to slice the end for latest version
grouping.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].text)
rows = grouping[-1]

#flatening the text into rows for the pandas dataframe
version_number = rows[0].text
pandas_row = [version_number]
pandas_rows = []
for r in rows[1:]:
    pandas_row = [version_number]
    for child in r.iter():
        if child.tag in ['botDialogGroup', 'label']:
            pandas_row.append(child.text)
    pandas_rows.append(pandas_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_rows, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree

bots = """your xml above"""
cols = ["BotVersion", "DialogGroup", "Dialog"]
rows = []
ver = 'v18'

root = etree.XML(bots)

for entry in root.xpath(f"//botVersions[//fullName[.='{ver}']]"):
    rows.append([ver,entry.xpath('//botDialogGroup/text()')[0],entry.xpath('//label/text()')[0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df
```

Output should be your expected df.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for the snippet I posted above, but when I try to use the 200K+ XML file instead of the small snippet I get an error stating "lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1".

Comment: @MyNameHere I'm afraid I can't help there - obviously, I don't have access to your actual xml; I can only assume that the xml in the question is a representative sample of the original.

Comment: I was assuming it would work since the formatting should be the same.  Here is a pastebin of another file that is smaller.  https://pastebin.com/aaDfBPUm

Comment: @MyNameHere First, that one has namespaces which must be deal with seperately. Second, it has different elements (`<developerName`> and `<label>` so you have to modify your expected output for it. Also, FYI, it's `v3` not `v18`.